# Best design/pattern to use for first-use tutorial in app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns, singleton

The background:

I have an app with 5 tabs.  The first time a user navigates to each tab, I would like to show a one-time "tutorial".  I intend to do this by creating a "TutorialViewController" that will handle displaying these "tutorial" views and will have buttons for next/back etc...

The problem:
I'm not sure the best pattern to use for implementing the logic for whether or not to show these screens and instantiating the "TutorialViewController" to display them.  The goal is to have a single line of code (a single method call) that would show the tutorial if necessary.  I'm trying to avoid duplication of code across the 5 view controllers.  The problem is where/how to implement this single method.  As a class method on TutorialViewController?  As a global C function?

Things I've considered:

1)  Implementing a class method on TutorialViewController called "displayTutorialIfNecessary".  In this case, each view controller that has a tutorial would call this class method from their "viewDidAppear" methods.  This class method would check to see if the tutorial has already been shown, and if not, it would instantiate a TutorialViewController object to handle to display it.  In this option, I guess I would have to pass in "self" from each calling view controller and the class method would use that to display the TutorialViewController.

2)  Implementing a class method on TutorialViewController called "tutorialShouldBeDisplayedForScreen: ".  In this option, each calling view controller would call this method, and if it returns true, each vc would instantiate and present the "TutorialViewController" which would handle displaying the tutorial.

I'm sure there is a "best practice" or a pattern that fits this scenario, but I'm not sure what the best implementation is.  Thanks in advance for your recommendations.

To summarize:  Instead of having something like this in each view controller:

```
 if ([TutorialViewController shouldDisplayTutorialForScreen:<someEnum>])
 {
     TutorialViewController *myTutorialVC = [[TutorialViewController alloc] init];
     [self displayModalViewController: myTutorialVC];
 }
```

I'd like something more like this:

```
 [FirstUseViewController displayTutorialIfNecessaryForScreen: <someEnum> forParentViewController: self];
```

Comment: I don't like directly calling code on another view controller class. So, I'd prefer 2 over 1, but why not a category method on `UIViewController`?

Comment: Not the best practice but a quick opinion: if there's no interaction between actual viewcontrollers and tutorial vc's, it seems to be a better idea not to add any code to actual vc's but instead do it at the container object that handles navigation between them.If any interaction is needed I'd just add a protocol with several options like handling beginning, ending and special stages of the tutorial.

Comment: @Marcus Adams  -- I agree with your comments, but a category on UIViewController doesn't really sound like the place for it either...

Comment: @ A-Live -- So you are suggesting the tab view controller should handle it?  The tutorial views will be presented modally over each view controller, so I'm not sure the container view controller should present a modal view controller over one of it's children...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

store the tutorial has shown state into `NSUserDefaults` and use **factory method design pattern** to let each UIViewController you'll need create and return tutorial `UIViewController` like:

```
- (UIViewController *)tutorialVC {
   return [[MYHomeScreenTutorialVC alloc] init];
}
```

Comment: You mean factory method design pattern?

Comment: This general idea will probably work.  I'll return a VC if it needs one, nil otherwise...